# How to set a value through binding for a Windows Forms UserControl in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, itemscontrol, windowsformshost

I'm dealing with this situation. I've got an items control where as item template I've got a windows forms userControl, and in code behind I'm setting the ItemsSource, but I don't know to set some data in the userControl.

In it UserControl I have some datagridview with specific structure, and WPF grid view is not useful for me. So I can't change this usercontrol.

```
       <ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="wfh" Grid.Column="2" Margin="10,0,0,10" />
                        <local:StudentHistoryUserControl />
                    </WindowsFormsHost>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

What can I do to access that usercontrol and set some values?

Answer (score 0):

[Databinding in WindowsForms and WPF Hybrid Apps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mhendersblog/archive/2005/10/03/476438.aspx)

Because Windows Forms is involved, XAML databinding will not work entirely. You need to set up data binding in the code behind.